# How can i convert string to implement it into database fields - Java/Spring/Postgres?

Tags: java, spring, string, postgresql, spring-boot

Ok. I've used `response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request, String.class)` to send some request to resource server. Under that, I have used `System.out.println("Response------" + response.getBody());` . With that executed, I'm receiving a string that is at the same time some kind of JSON object. Can you explain to me how can I convert it into some kind of entity so I can store it into my database? Thanks in advance!

That string that I'm receiving is like this: `{"access_token":"example...","expires_in":28800,"refresh_token":"example...","scope":"example...","token_type":"Bearer","user_id":"example..."}`

Comment: You would need to show us what that JSON looks like, and also tell us your desired database structure.

Comment: {"access_token":"example...","expires_in":28800,"refresh_token":"example...","scope":"example...","token_type":"Bearer","user_id":"example..."}

Also, database would store this fields separated.

Comment: If it is a single level (shallow) JSON object, then I believe Spring may already have the ability to map it to an object.  Poke around Stack Overflow, and you will easily turn something up.

Comment: add that in the post, not in comments @AleksandarLucic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ObjectMapper from Jackson(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourClass obj = objectMapper.readValue(yourJsonString, YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried this but if I try after that to print like `System.out.println(obj.getAccessToken());` , im getting null...

Comment: @AleksandarLucic What is the attribute name of the access token in YourClass? Because you have it as "access_token" in string then your attribute names in YourClass should match these keys in this json string. Thats the only reason I can see why you are getting null, I tried using "access_token" as my class field and it worked.

Comment: Yeah mate, the problem was about the name of class fields, they were different than those in JSON string. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    QuestionAnswerDTO questionAnswerDTOs = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<QuestionAnswerDTO>() {
        }.getType());
```

Here QuestionAnserDTO contains the same field as that of in JSON String.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the desired entity with jaxb, like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public final class Entity {

           private Integer id;

           private String name;

           public final Integer getId() {
              return this.id;
           }

           public final void setId(Integer id) {
              this.id = id;
           }

           public final String getName() {
              return this.name;
           }

           public final void setName( String name) {
              this.name = name;
           }
    }
```

And then you can do simple like:

```
response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request, Entity.class);
```